# Rails Validate String for URL "Safety"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, url

Let's say I have this route:

```
get 'post/:title' => 'post#show' , :as => 'show_post'
```

Anyone is able to create posts, and pick their own titles.
I don't want the title to contain characters like '/', '[', ']' as it could lead to bad urls generated with the helper method `show_post_path('blah')`. I'm sure there are other things than those character I mentioned I should be looking out for.

I'm looking for a way to validate against this in the post model.

/ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to make it will be use gem
[friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Rails `parameterize` method to `validate` the string 
Ex-

`result = yourstring.parameterize`

here is source http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize